# I'm new to atom (atom.io), I have downloaded it, and success installed it. But how to open this editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm new to atom (atom.io), I have downloaded it, and success installed it. But how to open this editor?

There is no shortcut in my desktop. And no atom icon on my start menu. How to open this editor?

Answer (score 0):

try to open a terminal and type "atom ." or, if it fail, check the installation guide [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/).